Shortest way to set a property after FirstOrDefault
Given request.Order type is ColumnName[]. I'm trying to write a one line piece of code equivalent to this incorrect code:
request.Order.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "From").Name = "FromDate";

What I need to do is to replace From by FromDate in the ColumnName where Name = "From", only if it exists (FirstOrDefault is not null).
The given code is obviously incorrect, because in the case of a null FirstOrDefault, .Name will throw an exception.
I'm trying to avoid multiple lines code or nested ifs.
In other words, I'm trying to replace:
var from = request.Order.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "From");

if (from is not null) 
{
    from.Name = "FromDate";
}

by a one line piece of code.
I'm using .NET 8
Any suggestions?

Linq being designed to query is not that good in modifying; technically we can put it as request.Order.Where(x => x.Name == "From").Select(x => x.Name = "FromDate").FirstOrDefault();. Don't do this in a real code, however

Urgh, please never do that!

I'm not saying you should add a SetName method, but if you did: request.Order.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "From")?.SetName("FromDate");

if (request.Order.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "From") is { } order)
{
    order.Name = "FromDate";
}

The slightly cryptic { } is a property pattern which matches any non-null object, i.e. a null test. (An alternative would be is ColumnName order). The advantage over an is not null pattern is that you get to assign the object to the variable order.

A slight variation is foreach (var order in request.Order.Where(x => x.Name == "From")) { ...} to update any/all matches. Add .Take(1) to limit update to the first (arbitrary) match if multiple are present.

If you're willing to invest in an extension method, that can be used for doing any operation on any object as long as it is != null:
public static class Ext
{
    public static T IfNotNull<T>(this T obj, Action<T> action) where T : class
    {
        if (obj is not null) action(obj);
        return obj;
    }
}

Usage:
var from = Order.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "From").IfNotNull(x => x.Name = "FromDate");

Demo Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wuChlH
